# help in proving double Derivative function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f(x)$ is twice differentiable in $[0,1]$ with $\min f(x)=-1$ and that $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

prove  $f''(c)≥8$, $c∈(0,1)$.

Comment: So the question is that given all of those criteria, can $c$ exist such that $f''(c)\geq 8$?

Comment: @TheCount Not "can c exist?", it's "must there exist such a c?".

Comment: @zhw. yes, thank you. i was hurrying when i asked, but see my response to the answer below.